# How to efficiently get coefficient of a specific degree of a polynomial?

Tags: polynomials

Suppose, given a list of $n+1$ roots $(a_0, a_1, \cdots, a_n)$ for a polynomial.

And denote its coefficient $C$ as $\sum_{j=0}^n c_j x^j = \prod_{i=0}^n(x-a_i)$.

My question is, if I'm only interested in $c_k$, (some arbitrary $k$) what's the most efficient way to obtain that?

I was thinking about $(n-k)$th root of unity. since with $x^k$, it becomes 1. But not sure whether if it will help.

Comment: Unsure what you are asking, so unsure if this response is on point.  If I understand your question correctly, see [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas).

Comment: thanks, I'm aware of Vieta's formula, and it is a very efficient way if my goal is to obtain all coefficient $C$. My question here is about some specific coefficient with degree $k$ term

Comment: Vieta's formulas allow you to focus only on a single coefficient and compute only that coefficient.  For example, if $(x - r_1)(x - r_2)(x - r_3) = x^3 + ax^2 + bx + c$ and you are only interested in the coefficient $b$, you can calculate that specific coefficient as $(r_1 r_2) + (r_1 r_3) + (r_2 r_3).$

Comment: right, but this is slightly complex with big $k$, i wonder if there is any more efficient way

Comment: If there is, it would have to yield the **exact** same computation as Vieta's formulas, since the formulas are accurate.